# Javascript recursion resetting the count

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to count the number of "file" in a JSON object recursively.

Here is my function,

```
function totalReports(object, count) { 
    count = count || 0;

    var key;
    for(key in object) {
        if(typeof object[key] == 'object') {
          if(object[key].type == 'file') {
             count += 1;
             console.log(count);            
          }
          console.log("count");            
          totalReports(object[key], count);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

And here is the JSON object,

```
jsonArray = {  
   "parent":{  
      "url":"parent.html",
      "name":"Parent",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "type":"folder",
            "name":"Folder 1",
            "url":"folder1.html",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "type":"file",
                  "name":"File 1",
                  "url":"folder1-file1.html",
                  "children":[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "type":"file",
                  "name":"File 2",
                  "url":"folder1-file2.html",
                  "children":[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "type":"file",
                  "name":"File 2",
                  "url":"folder1-file3.html",
                  "children":[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "type":"folder",
            "name":"Folder 2",
            "url":"folder2.html",
            "children":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "type":"folder",
            "name":"Folder 3",
            "url":"folder3.html",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "type":"file",
                  "name":"Folder3 File1",
                  "url":"folder3-file1",
                  "children":[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "type":"folder",
                  "name":"Folder3 Folder1",
                  "url":"folder3-file1",
                  "children":[  
                     {  
                        "type":"folder",
                        "name":"Folder3 Folder1 Folder1",
                        "url":"folder3-folder1-folder1",
                        "children":[  
                           {  
                              "type":"file",
                              "name":"Folder3 Folder1 Folder1 File1",
                              "url":"folder3-folder1-folder1-file1",
                              "children":[  

                              ]
                           },
                           {  
                              "type":"file",
                              "name":"Folder3 Folder1 Folder1 File2",
                              "url":"folder3-folder1-folder1-file2",
                              "children":[  

                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

And it is called as `console.log(totalReports(jsonArray))`. It is entering into the if loop right number of times, but it is not holding the value when it reaches the next sub array. The expected value here is 6 and it is entering into the if loop 6 times, but not sure why it is resetting the values, when it comes out.

Here is the fiddle for the same, https://jsbin.com/kogoko/edit?js,console,output

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `count = totalReports(object[key], count);`

Comment: @RomanHocke Ah, got it thanks :) You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need `count` for a different purpose, then I suggest to delete the parameter `count` and just return the locale `count`.

```js
function totalReports(object) {
    var count = 0;
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            if (object[key].type === 'file') {
                count++;
            }
            count += totalReports(object[key]);
        }
    });
    return count;
}

var jsonArray = { "parent": { "url": "parent.html", "name": "Parent", "children": [{ "type": "folder", "name": "Folder 1", "url": "folder1.html", "children": [{ "type": "file", "name": "File 1", "url": "folder1-file1.html", "children": [] }, { "type": "file", "name": "File 2", "url": "folder1-file2.html", "children": [] }, { "type": "file", "name": "File 2", "url": "folder1-file3.html", "children": [] }] }, { "type": "folder", "name": "Folder 2", "url": "folder2.html", "children": [] }, { "type": "folder", "name": "Folder 3", "url": "folder3.html", "children": [{ "type": "file", "name": "Folder3 File1", "url": "folder3-file1", "children": [] }, { "type": "folder", "name": "Folder3 Folder1", "url": "folder3-file1", "children": [{ "type": "folder", "name": "Folder3 Folder1 Folder1", "url": "folder3-folder1-folder1", "children": [{ "type": "file", "name": "Folder3 Folder1 Folder1 File1", "url": "folder3-folder1-folder1-file1", "children": [] }, { "type": "file", "name": "Folder3 Folder1 Folder1 File2", "url": "folder3-folder1-folder1-file2", "children": [] }] }] }] }] } },
    count = totalReports(jsonArray);

document.write(count);
```

Answer (score 3):

Count is a number and this is passed by value, not by reference in JavaScript. What you need to do is change this line.

```
totalReports(object[key], count);
```

to

```
count= totalReports(object[key], count);
```

Comment: Right and also passing the count argument is not needed then, which makes the code much more readable.

Comment: Well in order to not pass the count argument, he would actually need to write `count += totalReports(object[key], count);`, but yeah. It's much neater.